# android マーケットの判定を行いたい

Tags: android

こんにちは

[Detect if an Android app was downloaded from Google Play vs Amazon vs Other - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15348671/detect-if-an-android-app-was-downloaded-from-google-play-vs-amazon-vs-other)

上記の記事のようにマーケットの判定を行いたいのですが`getInstallerPackageName`で`NULL`を返し、エラーになります。
`getInstallerPackageName`でマーケット名を取得する方法をご教授お願いします。

Comment: どのマーケットからダウンロードしたアプリがそのAPIでnullになるのでしょうか？
リンク先の中に、ADBでインストールしたアプリの場合はnullになるとありますが、それではないでしょうか？

Comment: ありがとうございます！ADBで実行していました。
すいません。コメントを見逃していました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> リンク先の中に、ADBでインストールしたアプリの場合はnullになるとありますが、それではないでしょうか？ –  yuki 1 時間前

ADBで実行していたのが原因でした。